# Laravel Dropzonejs file validation in hasmany table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a laravel app that uploads files.  I need to check in the related table if the file exist.  My user model hasmany(assets)  The file info lives in the assets table.  I am trying to pull the name out of the table and verify it against the file being uploaded in dropzone.

Here is my dropzone script:

```
Dropzone.options.dropzoneUpload = {
paramName: "asset", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
maxFilesize: 2, // MB
accept: function(file, done) {
if (file.name == "{{$filename}}") {
  done("Naha, you don't.");
}
else { done(); }
}
};
```

My function that generates my view for my upload page looks like this

```
public function index()
{
    $filename = Auth::user()->assets->name;
    return view('upload.index')->with('filename', $filename);
}
```

I get an error returned on the name in the filename variable

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$name
```

I have no idea how to access the file name from the table and verify it with the script in the view.  Each user has multiple file names in the table.

Pre dropzone i was able to use this in my controller

```
foreach($userAssets as $asset)
        { 
            if($asset->name == $filename)
            { 
                return redirect('upload')->with('errornotice', 'A file with that name already exist');
            } 
        }
```

but that won't work in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said yourself that your `User` hasMany `Assets`, what exactly is `assets->name` supposed to print? The `name` of which `Asset`? Since you have many of those and `user->asset` is returning a Collection, you could probably iterate that collection, construct a JSON array out of all Asset `name`s and inject it into your JS. Then do a JavaScript `for`/`each` to check against all elements of the array. That's weak validation though, any user could edit the JS before submitting. If it's important to you that the filenames do not exist already, consider some kind of server-side validation.